# Dispatch is not a function error with createSlice()

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My objective is to get the customer details from a fake API through redux. I have migrated to using `createSlice()` to reduce the boilerplate, but I keep having that error. I have tried and researched as much as I can, but to no avail.

Here is a self contained code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gbhdd9?file=src/App.js

**App.js**

```
import React, { useCallback, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { customerApi } from './__fakeAPI__/customerApi';
import { getCustomer as getCustomerSlice } from './slices/customers';

export default function App() {
  const [customer, setCustomer] = useState(null);
  const getCustomer = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      //const data = await customerApi.getCustomer(); //works but not what I wanted
      const data = getCustomerSlice();
      setCustomer(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getCustomer();
  }, [getCustomer]);

  return <div>{console.log(customer)}</div>;
}
```

**slices/customers.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { customerApi } from '../__fakeAPI__/customerApi';

const initialState = {
  customer: {}
};

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'customers',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    getCustomer(state, action) {
      state.customer = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

export const { reducer } = slice;

export const getCustomer = () => async dispatch => {
  const data = await customerApi.getCustomer();
  //dispatch seems to not be working
  dispatch(slice.actions.getCustomer(data));
};

export default slice;
```

Comment: I believe you still need to dispatch this `getCustomer` action, though you've certainly coded this in what appears to be a cart-before-the-horse way. You could use [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) to create your asynchronous action creators.

Comment: You are making an async action , so you should be using RTK query if you are using the redux toolkit - https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview . Also i see that you are not dispatching an action from your component . You should not call the slice directly from your component . I recommend you to go through the Redux toolkit documentation which is pretty good .

Comment: @DrewReese I actually did try to do that, however, there's still an issue that I'm not quite sure of. `const data = await dispatch(getCustomerSlice());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to dispatch your action to make it work, to access customer you can use useSelector to get access to your state :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v4u5ft?file=src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a few changes to App.js to make this work.

- The `getCustomerSlice()` method is an action creator and in your case, it returns a thunk, and to get access to the `dispatch` method in a thunk, you must first dispatch the action/function returned from that action creator i.e in App.js

```js
export default function App() {
  ...
  const getCustomer = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const data = dispatch(getCustomerSlice());
      ...
  }, []);
  ...
}
```

- To get access to the dispatch method in App.js, import the `useDispatch` from react-redux, `useDispatch` is a function that returns the dispatch method i.e

```js
...
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux"
...

export default function App() {
const dispatch = useDispatch()
  ...
  const getCustomer = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const data = dispatch(getCustomerSlice());
      ...
  }, []);
  ...
}
```

When you do this redux-thunk will automatically supply `dispatch, getState` as parameters to any function that is returned from an action creator. This will cause your implementation to update your store properly.

Since you are expecting a return value from your dispatch method, make this modification to your customers.js file

```js
...
export const getCustomer = () => async dispatch => {
  const data = await customerApi.getCustomer();
  //dispatch seems to not be working
  dispatch(slice.actions.getCustomer(data));
  // return the data
  return data;
};
...
```

then in your App.js file await the dispatch function since you defined it as async

```js
...
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux"
...

export default function App() {
const dispatch = useDispatch()
  ...
  const getCustomer = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const data = await dispatch(getCustomerSlice());
      ...
  }, []);
  ...
}
```

TLDR
Your App.js should now look like this.

```js
import React, { useCallback, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { customerApi } from './__fakeAPI__/customerApi';
import { useSelector, useDispatch} from "react-redux"
import { getCustomer as getCustomerSlice } from './slices/customers';

export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [customer, setCustomer] = useState(null);
  const getCustomer = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      //const data = await customerApi.getCustomer(); //works but not what I wanted
      const data = await dispatch(getCustomerSlice());
      setCustomer(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getCustomer();
  }, [getCustomer]);

  return <div>{console.log("customers",customer)}</div>;
}
```

And your customers.js like this

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { customerApi } from '../__fakeAPI__/customerApi';

const initialState = {
  customer: {}
};

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'customers',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    getCustomer(state, action) {
      state.customer = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

export const { reducer } = slice;

export const getCustomer = () => async dispatch => {
  const data = await customerApi.getCustomer();
  //dispatch seems to not be working
  dispatch(slice.actions.getCustomer(data));
  return data;
};

export default slice;
```

it is important to note that your component has not subscribed to the store yet. so if the customers object in the store is modified by another component then this component won't re-render, to fix this look up the `useSelector` hook from react-redux

Comment: You explained that beautifully. In using the `useSelector` hook,  do you think that the answer provided by Nicolas is the most correct one?

Comment: Yes, it is. It is the simplest way of having a component subscribe to the store in redux (a subscription is needed to ensure your component will re-render when the store updates). you will notice that Nicolas's implementation eliminated the need for a local state in your app.js file.